# MATLAB: parfor loop freezing with a large data set

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, freeze

I have a large set of images that I am processing within a **`parfor`** loop.

The image set is around 1000 images and the `parfor` loop works great if I only run it on a small subset of that ( 100 or so ), but when I run it on the whole set, it freezes MATLAB ( physical memory up at near 96%, CPU down to 0-1% ).

I'm new to `parfor` loops, I'm sure I'm doing this in a not smart way.

There must be a way to run this, where I don't have to load the full `imageset` within each `parfor` iteration.

```
imageset=load(imagefile);

parfor i = 1:length( imageset )
       imagesetP = imageset;
       image     = imagesetP(:,:,i);
       % bunch of functions performed on an image;
end
```

I'm guessing MATLAB is creating multiple versions of the full `imageset`, which is taking up too much memory and freezing things up.

Not sure why this wouldn't be the case when I run this on a smaller subset though
( **`parfor i = length( imageset ) / 10`** ).

I assume there's something better than just splitting it:

```
imageset=load(imagefile);

for j=0:(length(imageset)/100)-1
    subset=imageset(:,:,(1+(j*100)):(j+1)*100)

        parfor i=1:length(imageset)
             imagesetP=subset;
             image=imagesetP(:,:,i);
             %bunch of functions performed on image;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the size/type of your `imageset` variable? If it's a 3D numeric array, it might work simply to ensure you [*slice*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variable.html) but don't *broadcast* the array, i.e.

```
imageset=load(imagefile);

parfor i = 1:length( imageset )
    image = imageset(:,:,i);
    % ...  
end
```

An array is [*broadcast*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/broadcast-variable.html) into a `parfor` loop if you access it without indexing inside the loop. This causes a copy of the array to be made on each worker.

Answer (score -2):

> **a prologue**
> on Edric's objection: ***Nothing in the*** OP's **code says that 1000 workers are going to be used.**
> Right, this information is not included in the MATLAB code, but this local-context is rather stored inside another place, the cluster configuration profile ( as was explicitly demonstrated in the bottom of this post )
> The rest of the post will be left without change, for demonstrating the problems from over-subscribed resources as sharp as possible. Arcane Hawks may kindly substitute by heart the term "1000" with "several".
> Users without respect for underlying architectures may similarly ( and do ) try to move 4-data-flow streams across just 2-channel memory sub-system or pay zero attention to cache-friendly indexing, (non)-coalesced memory-access patterns and may ask similar questions without trying to pay due interest and proper care on how the Non-Uniform-Memory-Architectures actually work.
> Parallel code-execution is way more a very delicate art of harnessing and balancing { multi- | many-}-core CPU resources + actual cache-hierarchies + physical memory-subsystem architecture capabilities, if one strives for gaining increased performance, than a just syntax option to type into a SLOC.

### This is not a freeze,

this is a result of an explicit instruction to run ~ 1000 processes in a MATLAB parallel-pool at once, which is syntactically correct, but unless one operates a system having 1000+ CPU-cores, the operating system will go mad in doing whatever possible to fair-schedule all the O/S-kernel + user-space processes plus those newly requested 1000+ parallel-pool replicas of the MATLAB processing.

---

### Result?
AN AWFULL CONCURRENCY TRAFFIC JAM  <sup>( unless a 1000+ CPU host / OS )</sup>

( + increased by all the associated context-switching, moving memory working-sets, swapping like a hell ... needless to tell you the story you have seen right on your desk )

---

### Solution?

**Do not "over-subscribe" resources** on any "long"- and "dense"-computing tasks.

Why? **The "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`-scheduling will immediately stop delivering any benefits** that might have been considered handy on un(der)-loaded system-state, where resources sharing had so enough spare-capacity so as to mask efficiently both the costs-of-sharing and all the context-switching add-on overheads ( whereas any "fat"-calculus meat will always add overheads and will *almost*-"freeze", if the levels of over-loading would go as wild as noted above ).

Given the intention is not actually a need to execute the code in a true **`[PARALLEL]`** scheduling fashion, but rather ( assumed a will ) to run more than one task at a time in pure `[SERIAL]` fashion, rather experiment with a use of hardware-capacity aware setup, alike:

```
M = 3;                                 %%% M: specifies maximum number of workers
parfor ( i = 1:length( imageset ), M ) %%% M < parcluster('local').NumWorkers;
       %% whatever bunch of functions performed in [SEQ] schedule on an image;
       %%
```

---

There are additional steps and measures for indeed HPC processing, that go beyond this post. It is a common practice to even disable HT-thread-switching on HPC platforms, so as to eliminate depleted L1/L2/L3-artifacts and make all CPU-cores smoothly drive the continuous, uninterrupted stream of processing.

```
feature('numcores')
MATLAB detected: 4 physical cores.
MATLAB detected: 8 logical cores.
MATLAB was assigned: 8 logical cores by the OS.
MATLAB is using: 4 logical cores.
MATLAB is not using all logical cores because hyper-threading is enabled.

ans =

       4
```

Comment: Nothing in the OP's code says that 1000 workers are going to be used. The number of workers used by `parfor` is limited by the number of workers in the parallel pool - which is determined by the number of workers available in the corresponding cluster profile. By default, using the `local` cluster type, this is already set to `feature('numcores')`.